# Not sure how to build OpenCV for MinGW

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

TL;DR;

I am trying to build OpenCV for MinGW. `cmake` keeps complaining about no sane CXX compiler, although I can compile sample code with g++.exe.

---

Long version

I tried finding a binary for MinGW, [but this didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094538/problems-linking-to-opencv-from-mingw).

I tried compiling for MinGW but that fails with some error about sh.exe not being in $PATH. I am puzzled, as renaming the target file on the filesystem did not resolve the issue.

```
E:\work\opencv\mybuild> cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ../sources
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeMin
GWFindMake.cmake:22 (message):
  sh.exe was found in your PATH, here:


  C:/Users/desuna/AppData/Local/GitHub/PortableGit_054f2e797ebafd44a30203088cd3d
58663c627ef/bin/sh.exe


  For MinGW make to work correctly sh.exe must NOT be in your path.

  Run cmake from a shell that does not have sh.exe in your PATH.

  If you want to use a UNIX shell, then use MSYS Makefiles.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:56 (project)


CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Ma
kefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a differe
nt build tool.
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Ma
kefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a differe
nt build tool.
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be
 built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be
 built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: E:/work/opencv/mybuild/CMakeFiles
/2.8.12.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be
 built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be
 built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: E:/work/opencv/mybuild/CMakeFiles
/2.8.12.2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I was advised later, that MSYS makefiles do not have this requirement. Now there was an error about the C++ compiler. However, the C++ compiler is correctly identified. Also, I tried compiling a dummy test.cxx program and it worked.

```
E:\work\opencv\mybuild> cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ../sources
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTes
tCXXCompiler.cmake:54 (message):
  The C++ compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe" is not able to compile a simple
  test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: E:/work/opencv/mybuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
```

The error log is:

```
Determining if the CXX compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: E:/work/opencv/mybuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:C:/PROGRA~2/GnuWin32/bin/make.exe "cmTryCompileExec1507552824/fast"
C:/PROGRA~2/GnuWin32/bin/make.exe -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1507552824.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1507552824.dir/build

make.exe[1]: Entering directory `E:/work/opencv/mybuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

"/C/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/bin/cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report /E/work/opencv/mybuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1

Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1507552824.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj
/C/MinGW/bin/g++.exe     -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1507552824.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -c /E/work/opencv/mybuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, /C/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1507552824.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -c /E/work/opencv/mybuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx, ...) failed.

make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.


make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1507552824.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj] Error 2

make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `E:/work/opencv/mybuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

make.exe: *** [cmTryCompileExec1507552824/fast] Error 2
```

My aim is to have one-step build under Windows 7 for a small application in C++, that links against onecv_core, opencv_highgui and several more. For this, it appears that I need to build OpenCV from source with gcc under mingw. Please advise what is the correct approach to that.

---

EDIT:

I tried **barek**'s answer, and the error is the same as with MSYS target - no sane c++ compiler. I next tried `cmake-gui`, specifying compilers. Also, I made sure that MinGW/bin is in my path. Follows the error message:

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: E:/work/opencv/mybuild/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: E:/work/opencv/mybuild/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I suspect the problem lies in somethign really stupid, like CMAKE not being able to change directories, due to impropper MinGW isntallation.

[Here](http://ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=55238) a discussion can be found, but I:

- Checked that MinGW/bin is in my path
- Also specified the C and C++ compiler paths manually in `cmake-gui`
- Installed MinGW with the installer from SourceForge and selected the tickbox "Alter PATH".

Comment: avoid msys, as it's messing with pathes, - just use a regular cmd.exe to run cmake, and build a regular MinGW Makefile. also have the mingw bins on the PATH, because it wants to run mingw32-make instead of make then

Comment: @berak, thanks for the tip. Do you have any advice how to cope with `For MinGW make to work correctly sh.exe must NOT be in your path.`? I tied renaming the file and then using `cmd.exe`, but there was no change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. cleanup! delete all previous build attempts, `CmakeFile.cache`, etc.
2. have MingW/bin on the path
3. make a folder within the opencv dir, called build_mingw, `cd` there
4. `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=mingw32-g++.exe -D CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=mingw32-make.exe ..` # <-- note the dots at the end
5. `mingw32-make`
6. `mingw32-make install`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was missing `mingw32-make`. I found this out by the help of `cmake-gui` and selected advanced option to list all cmake variables.

Comment: By the way, maybe an out of source build would be cleaner? For example `../build/mingw/`.

Comment: yes, true. on the other hand, most people only keep the install dir and throw away the whole build folder (~2gb!)

Comment: I get to 62%, then this error appears: "modules\videoio\CMakeFiles\opencv_videoio.dir\build.make:126: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_dshow.cpp.obj' failed". What must I do?

Answer (score 0):

I tried everthing mentioned here and [CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141608/cmake-make-program-not-found) but nothing helped. Then restarted the computer and it works.