# How to build MinGW binaries in OpenCV for Windows?

Tags: c++, opencv, mingw

I can't build MinGW binaries in OpenCV. I am using Code::Blocks and need to include OpenCV libraries in my C++ project.

I searched the web for hours for a solution, but i can't find any. I tried CMake, but get the following error:

> CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding
>   to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably
>   need to select a different build tool.

I searched the web for this error, but all the proposed solutions are too advanced for me.

Is there a way to build MinGW **without** CMake? My reason for not want to use CMake is that it seems like i will get too much trouble with it. If it's not possible (or more difficult) to not use CMake, is anyone knows how to get around with aforementioned error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193881/not-sure-how-to-build-opencv-for-mingw/24199764#24199764

Comment: "Is there a way to build MinGW without CMake?" - no. just get over it.

Comment: @berak What do you mean by "MingW/bin on the path"? Also, where do i write the command in step 4?