# Error in CMake for OpenCV

Tags: windows, opencv, cmake, mingw32

CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.

Comment: have a [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193881/not-sure-how-to-build-opencv-for-mingw/24199764#24199764)

Comment: I am using CMake GUI. help me proceed through GUI

Comment: try to locate CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM. (advanced settings). if it's not there, **add** a new entry: `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` `path\to\mingw32-make.exe`

Comment: you can add windows in your tags, so people who can just work with linux won't come to this thread.