# CMake error trying to setup openCV, MinGW compiler

Tags: c++, c, windows, opencv, gcc

I've been trying to build openCV using CMake, but keep running into errors. I think I have MinGW setup properly.

I'm running the following command in C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw:

> cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=mingw32-g++.exe -D
>   CMAKE-MAKE_PROGRAM=mingw32-make.exe ../../../sources

This gives the following error:

> -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
>   -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
>   -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-g++.exe CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was:
>   "mingw32-make.exe" "cmTryCompileExec1510977625/fast"
>   -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-g++.exe -- broken CMake Error at C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:54
>   (message):   The C++ compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-g++.exe" is not
>   able to compile a simple test program.
>
> It fails with the following output:
>
> ```
> Change Dir: C:/opencv/build/x86/mingw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
> ```
>
> Run Build Command: "mingw32-make.exe"
>   "cmTryCompileExec1510977625/fast"
>
> The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Generator: execution of make failed.

I was following the instructions found in berak's response to this question:
[Not sure how to build OpenCV for MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193881/not-sure-how-to-build-opencv-for-mingw)

Please provide some suggestions!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it should not be necessary to set your compiler and `make` specifically. So, calling

```
$ cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ../../../sources
```

should be enough.

If you really want to specify the compiler, you need to set the environment variables `CC` and `CXX`, which CMake respects:

```
$ export CC=/absolute/path/to/your/mingw32-gcc.exe
$ export CXX=/absolute/path/to/your/mingw32-g++.exe
$ cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ../../../sources
```