# Error in Generating opencv4Android from trunk

Tags: c++, opencv, android-studio, android

I need to use nonfree module in my app. I have been trying to build the app in the Android Studio native environment using ndk. I followed the tutorial [here](https://sites.google.com/site/wghsite/technical-notes/sift_surf_opencv_android) and generated .so files and added them to my project.

But then my app was crashing whenever I use opencv libraries. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291148/cannot-use-opencvc-in-android-studio) is the problem I faced. So I thought of rebuilding the entire opencv library for Android Studio. I followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193881/not-sure-how-to-build-opencv-for-mingw), generated the files and steps [here](https://zami0xzami.wordpress.com/2016/03/17/building-opencv-for-android-from-source/) to build the libraries. I got to 29% and this following error occurred.

[image].

Comment: We prefer error messages to be supplied as text, so that the page works with clipboards, search engines and screen-readers. Would you change it please? There is a copy feature in the Windows command program.

Comment: I solved the issue with some help and I cannot run it again to get those messages. But, I will keep in my mind the issues you pointed it out when posting next time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [***here***](http://answers.opencv.org/question/51987/highgui-window_w32cpp-error-tbbuttoninfo-was-not-declared-in-this-scope/). For anyone looking for a solution for the above error in the future. I am writing it down.

Find "commctrl.h" in MinGW directory and open it. There may be two files with the same name. Open both of them and change

```html
#if 0
#define _WIN32_IE   0x0300
#endif
```

to

```html
#if 1
#define _WIN32_IE   0x0500
#endif
```